# Improve the Json data editing form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, next.js

[image: json editing form]

I have created such a form for editing json data using the usual `<textarea />` tag, but I would like to make it more friendly in terms of editing, can you tell me some tools that will help make the form better. I would also like to remove the red backlight in the test if possible.

Perhaps there are already ready-made components and implementations of this. I would be very grateful.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

To remove the red backlight, I think you may try with the `spellcheck` attribute.

```js
<textarea spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

About making your input friendly, we have many libraries to do this. You may find it in Google. Some library I've used `react-simple-code-editor`, `@uiw/react-textarea-code-editor`. You may find more to got a library to fit your require.